# Work Around For Accessing Field of Abstract Class in Subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I realize this question is a duplicate many times over, but here goes:

I've been tasked for homework to create (using Java) an abstract class called Triangle that has abstract methods getArea() and getPerimeter() and a constructor which takes in a double representing the side length (you'll see why it's only one value in a second). I'm supposed to create concrete subclasses EquilateralTriangle and RightTriangle that extend Triangle and respectively implement getArea() and getPerimeter(), and they are also meant to have constructors which take in a double for the side length.

The problem I've run into is not knowing how to store the side length, given that it's meant to be stored in the field belonging to Triangle, the superclass of each subclass which needs to access that field in its own area and perimeter methods. I started out thinking I could keep it as a private field in Triangle, and that it would simply be inherited in each subclass and set correctly in each subclass' constructor via calls to super(). The compiler complained about the field having private access in Triangle, so I switched the field to protected, and it now compiles but gives me the run-time error "java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field Triangle.side from class EquilateralTriangle." I'm not sure how to go about designing this in a way that doesn't involve explicitly creating a field to hold side length in each of the subclasses, or something like that. Here's my current code:

```
public abstract class Triangle {
    protected double side;
    public abstract double getArea();
    public abstract double getPerimeter();
    public double getRatio() {
        return getArea() / getPerimeter();
    }
    public Triangle(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Triangle: SideLen = " + this.side 
          + " || Area = " + getArea()
          + " || Perimeter = " + getPerimeter()
          + " || Ratio = " + getRatio();
    }
 }

public class EquilateralTriangle extends Triangle {
    private static final double AREA_COEFFICIENT = Math.sqrt(3) / 4;
    public EquilateralTriangle(double side) {
        super(side);
    }
    public double getArea() {
        return AREA_COEFFICIENT * this.side * this.side;
    }
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return this.side * 3;
    }

}


public class RightTriangle extends Triangle {
    private static final double PERIMETER_COEFFICIENT = Math.sqrt(2) + 2;
    public double getArea() {
        return this.side * this.side / 2;
    }
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return this.side * PERIMETER_COEFFICIENT;
    }
    public RightTriangle(double side) {
        super(side);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a `getter` method?

Comment: Ah... It crossed my mind but I never actually tried it — that fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the approach of using a protected field is fine. It may be better to make it private and then add a `protected double getSide()` in the `Triange` class.

```
    public static abstract class Triangle {
      private double side;
      public abstract double getArea();
      public abstract double getPerimeter();
      public double getRatio() {
        return getArea() / getPerimeter();
      }
      public Triangle(double side) {
        this.side = side;
      }

      protected double getSide()
      {
          return this.side;
      }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Triangle: SideLen = " + this.side 
          + " || Area = " + getArea()
          + " || Perimeter = " + getPerimeter()
          + " || Ratio = " + getRatio();
    }
 }
```

In the subclasses, replaced `this.side` with `getSide()`.